# Regex including what is supposed to be non-capturing group in result

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following simple test where i'm trying to get the Regex pattern such that it yanks the executable name without the ".exe" suffix.
 
It appears my non-capturing group setting `(?:\\.exe)` isn't working or i'm misunderstanding how its intended to work.
 
Both [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) show the same result and the former confirms that "(?:\.exe)" is a non-capturing match.
 
Any thoughts on what i'm doing wrong?

```
// test variable for what i would otherwise acquire from Environment.CommandLine
var testEcl = "\"D:\\src\\repos\\myprj\\bin\\Debug\\MyApp.exe\" /?"
var asmName = Regex.Match(testEcl, @"[^\\]+(?:\.exe)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
// expecting "MyApp" but I get "MyApp.exe"
```

I have been able to extract the value i wanted by using a matching pattern with group names defined, as shown in the following, but would like to understand why non-capturing group setting approach didn't work the way i expected it to.

```
// test variable for what i would otherwise acquire from Environment.CommandLine
var testEcl = "\"D:\\src\\repos\\myprj\\bin\\Debug\\MyApp.exe\" /?"
var asmName = Regex.Match(Environment.CommandLine, @"(?<fname>[^\\]+)(?<ext>\.exe)", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["fname"].Value;
// get the desired "MyApp" result
```

/eoq

Comment: to get `MyApp` from `var testEcl = "\"D:\\src\\repos\\myprj\\bin\\Debug\\MyApp.exe\" /?"` you can use `Path.GetFileName` as  `string directory = Path.GetFileName(testEcl);`

Comment: @Ashik, thanks for non-regex based suggestion. Tried Path.GetFileName() and .GetFileNameWithoutExtension() both throw System.ArgumentException "Illegal characters in path." result.

Comment: Your path includes `"` at the beginning and at the end.Try droping the quotes, and it'll be ok

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that matches and still *consumes* the text. It means the part of text this group matches is still added to the overall match value.

**In general**, if you want to match something but not consume, you need to use *lookarounds*. So, if you need to match something that is followed with a specific string, use a *positive lookahead*, `(?=...)` construct:

```
some_pattern(?=specific string) // if specific string comes immmediately after pattern
some_pattern(?=.*specific string) // if specific string comes anywhere after pattern
```

If you need to match but "exclude from match" some specific text before, use a *positive lookbehind*:

```
(?<=specific string)some_pattern // if specific string comes immmediately before pattern
(?<=specific string.*?)some_pattern // if specific string comes anywhere before pattern
```

Note that `.*?` or `.*` - that is, patterns with `*`, `+`, `?`, `{2,}` or even `{1,3}` quantifiers - in lookbehind patterns are not always supported by regex engines, however, C# .NET regex engine luckily supports them. They are also supported by Python PyPi `regex` module, Vim, JGSoft software and now by ECMAScript 2018 compliant JavaScript environments.

**In this case**, you may capture what you need to get and just match the context without capturing:

```
var testEcl = "\"D:\\src\\repos\\myprj\\bin\\Debug\\MyApp.exe\" /?";
var asmName = string.Empty; 
var m = Regex.Match(testEcl, @"([^\\]+)\.exe", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success)
{
    asmName = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
Console.WriteLine(asmName);
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/51Hee5)

**Details**

- `([^\\]+)` - *Capturing group 1*: one or more chars other than `\`
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `exe` - a literal `exe` substring.

Since we are only interested in capturing group #1 contents, we grab `m.Groups[1].Value`, and not the whole `m.Value` (that contains `.exe`).

Answer (score 3):

You're using a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). The emphasis is on the word *group* here; the *group* does not capture the `.exe`, but the regex in general still does.

You're probably wanting to use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which just asserts that the string must meet a criteria for the match to be valid, though that criteria is not captured.

**In other words, you want `(?=`, not `(?:`, at the start of your group.**

The former is only if you are enumerating [the `Groups` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups) of the [`Match` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match); in your case, you're just using [the `Value` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value?view=netframework-4.7), so there's no distinction between a normal group `(\.exe)` and a non-capturing group `(?:\.exe)`.

To see the distinction, consider this test program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var positiveInput = "\"D:\\src\\repos\\myprj\\bin\\Debug\\MyApp.exe\" /?";
    Test(positiveInput, @"[^\\]+(\.exe)");
    Test(positiveInput, @"[^\\]+(?:\.exe)");
    Test(positiveInput, @"[^\\]+(?=\.exe)");

    var negativeInput = "\"D:\\src\\repos\\myprj\\bin\\Debug\\MyApp.dll\" /?";
    Test(negativeInput, @"[^\\]+(?=\.exe)");
}

static void Test(String input, String pattern)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Input: {input}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Regex pattern: {pattern}");

    var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Matched: " + match.Value);
        for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Groups[{i}]: {match.Groups[i]}");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No match.");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("---");
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Input: "D:\src\repos\myprj\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe" /?
Regex pattern: [^\\]+(\.exe)
Matched: MyApp.exe
Groups[0]: MyApp.exe
Groups[1]: .exe
---
Input: "D:\src\repos\myprj\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe" /?
Regex pattern: [^\\]+(?:\.exe)
Matched: MyApp.exe
Groups[0]: MyApp.exe
---
Input: "D:\src\repos\myprj\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe" /?
Regex pattern: [^\\]+(?=\.exe)
Matched: MyApp
Groups[0]: MyApp
---
Input: "D:\src\repos\myprj\bin\Debug\MyApp.dll" /?
Regex pattern: [^\\]+(?=\.exe)
No match.
---
```

The first regex (`@"[^\\]+(\.exe)"`) has `\.exe` as just a normal group.
When we enumerate the Groups property, we see that `.exe` is indeed a group captured in our input. 
(Note that the entire regex is itself a group, hence `Groups[0]` is equal to `Value`).

The second regex (`@"[^\\]+(?:\.exe)"`) is the one provided in your question. 
The only difference compared to the previous scenario is that the Groups property doesn't contain `.exe` as one of its entries.

The third regex (`@"[^\\]+(?=\.exe)"`) is the one I'm suggesting you use. 
Now, the `.exe` part of the input isn't captured by the regex at all, but a regex won't match a string unless it ends in `.exe`, as the fourth scenario illustrates.

Answer (score 1):

It would match the non capturing group but won't capture it, so if you want the non captured part you should access the capture group instead of the whole match

you can access groups in

```
var asmName = Regex.Match(testEcl, @"([^\\]+)(?:\.exe)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
asmName.Groups[1].Value
```

the demo for the regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/mDZtln/1)

Comment: Thanks for response.  I'm looking for the captured part of match not the part denoted as a non-capturing group by `(?: )` setting.  When i try the above retrieving .Groups[1].Value produces "" empty string and .Groups[0].Value is the same result i'm getting if i just pull .Value and Groups.Count is 1.

Comment: Thanks that works now.  Based on other response I the (?: ) non-capturing setting is not even required in this case given having it or not doesn't affect the unnamed capturing group ( ) setting from putting the desired match in Group[1].Value